# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in [null]

Tags: angular

In my Angular 2 project ListingService can't get data from server via post. I'm getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in [null]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
at ListingService.getListings (http://localhost:3000/app/listing.service.js:30:30)
at ListingsComponent.getListings (http://localhost:3000/app/listings.component.js:45:41)
at ListingsComponent.ngOnInit (http://localhost:3000/app/listings.component.js:41:26)
at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_HostListingsComponent_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:10897:14), <anonymous>:22:99)
at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8824:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8807:12)
at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8871:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8808:12)
at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8877:14)
at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:8811:12)
```

My ListingService.ts looks like this:

```
import {Injectable, Injector} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Listing} from './listing';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class ListingService {
 http: Http;
 listings: Array<Listing>;
 getListings() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://144.376.29.134:and-so-on', JSON.stringify(
    {"id":1, "title": "Title", "description": "Проводите", "discount": "21%", "imageUrl": "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports", "tags": [{"tag": "Еда"}]
    }),{headers:headers}
    ).map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe((res:Array<Listing>) => this.listings = res);
    return Promise.resolve(this.listings);
 }
 getListing(id: number) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.listings)
    .then(listings => listings.filter(l => l.id === id)[0]);
 }
}
```

And the ListingsComponent, which uses ListingService, looks like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Listing} from './listing';
import {ListingService} from './listing.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
  ....
})
export class ListingsComponent implements OnInit {
 listings: Array<Listing>;
 constructor(private listingService:ListingService, private _router: Router) {}
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getListings();
 }
 getListings() {
  this.listingService.getListings().then(listings => this.listings = listings);
 }
 getListing(id: number) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.listings)
  .then(listings => listings.filter(l => l.id === id)[0]);
 }
 gotoDetail(listing: Listing) {
  this._router.navigate(['ListingDetail', { id: listing.id }]);
 }
}
```

What can be problem of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS` to either the component `providers` array like this:

```
providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
```

or preferably in the bootstrap like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

And you are missing the `constructor` http injection in the `ListingService`:

```
export class ListingService {
   constructor(private http : Http){}
}
```

**addendum**

The reason you are not receiving any listings is because you are using a Promise instead of Observable:

in `getListings()` in `ListingService` return this:

```
return this.http.post("bla bla").map(res => res.json).map((res) => {
    return this.listings = res;
});
```

then subscribe to this in the `getListings()` in the `ListingsComponent`:

```
getListings() {
  this.listingService.getListings().subscribe(listings => this.listings = listings);
}
```

Comment: I added HTTP_PROVIDERS to bootstrap before. I've added constructor to ListingService like you wrote, errors have disappeared. But data (listings) has not shown yet ((

Comment: That is a completely different problem. You are using Promises instead of the Observables/Subscribers that angular provides. I suggest you create another question. But to give you some pointers, ill make a little addendum to my post

Comment: YOU ARE THE GENIUS! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have imported Http and added below constructor code in my component `constructor(private http:Http) { }` still it's saying `Cannot read property 'post' of undefined` please help @PierreDuc

Answer (score 0):

You should return the observable object from your request in the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {
  constructor(http:Http/*, routeParams: RouteParams*/) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getCompanies() {
    return this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/')
            .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

And subscribe a listener from your component:

```
export class CompanyList implements OnInit {
  public companies: Company[];

  constructor(private service: CompanyService) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCompanies().subscribe(
      data => this.companies = data);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry