# ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I had an issue on

> Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in angular 2

on submitting the form, a function is called, here is the code

```js
onSubmit() {
  console.log("onsubmit->", this.addForm.value);
  let addArray = this.addForm.value;
  this._employeeservice.addEmployeeCollection(addArray)
    .subscribe(sample => {
      this.dbemp.push(sample);
    });
  this.addForm.reset();
  this.SubmitToast();
}
```

`addEmployeeCollection()` code is here

```js
addEmployeeCollection(addArray: EmployeeSchema) {
  let url: string = Constants.DOMAIN + Constants.CREATE_EMPLOYEE_ROUTE;
  console.log('addArray at emplyee service', addArray)
  var body = addArray;
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  let options = {
    headers: headers
  };
  let token = localStorage.getItem('realtoken');
  options.headers.set('Authorization', ` ${token}`);
  return this.http.post(url, body, options).map(res => res.json()).catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450410/typeerror-cannot-read-property-post-of-undefined-in-null

Comment: please provide code where you instantiate `this.http` service.

Comment: The Http service is not injected.

Comment: export class EmployeeService{public http:Http}

Comment: @sandhiyavelayutham You need to inject the http in the constructor: `constructor(private http: Http) { }`

Comment: @AJT_82, thanks a lot, really hellped, i learned a new hack

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments, we learned that the HTTP wasn't injected properly, which caused `this.http` to be `undefined`.

Instead of marking the http in the service like so:

```
export class EmployeeService {
  public http: Http;
}
```

it should be injected in the constructor:

```
export class EmployeeService {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's safer to empty your form once you got your success call back. So try this :

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log("onsubmit->", this.addForm.value);
  let addArray = this.addForm.value;
  this._employeeservice.addEmployeeCollection(addArray)
    .subscribe(sample => {
      this.dbemp.push(sample);
      this.addForm.reset(); //move this in the subscribe area
      this.SubmitToast();
    });
}
```